# Need to parse response from the database using sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working on an endpoint with Node and sequelize, which sole responsibility is to provide the tags of a provided comma separated entities ids. So the expected response is:

```json
{
    "entity1_id": ["tag1", "tag2",],
    "entity2_id": ["tag3", "tag4"],
}
```

and i had no trouble to achieve it but I realized i was instantiating the entities in a for loop and then asking for their tags, which is horrible for performance.
So instead of doing that i decided to use a raw query:

```js
import { QueryTypes } from "sequelize"; 
await this.connection.query(
  `SELECT tr.external_id, ta.name from transactions tr 
      INNER JOIN  tag_taggable tt ON tt.taggable_id = tr.id AND tt.taggable_type = '${taggableType}' 
      INNER JOIN tags ta ON tt.tag_id = ta.id WHERE tr.external_id IN ('${ids.join("','")}'
);`, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

where ids is a `string[]` and `external_id` is the identifier of the entity i'm using.

Now I get a result like this:

```js
[
  { external_id: 'entity1_id', name: 'tag1' },
  { external_id: 'entity1_id', name: 'tag2' },
  { external_id: 'entity2_id', name: 'tag3' },
  { external_id: 'entity1_id', name: 'tag4' }
]
```

and I was wandering about what i need to do to acheive the response i was sending before. Something in the SQL side??, and if not, what is the best approach to do it in the JS side?? (reducer? for of?).

Answer (score 0):

For the JS side i came up to a `for of` and a `reduce`

```js
const alreadyPushedIds: string[] = [];
const finalResult: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};
for (const result of results) {
    if (alreadyPushedIds.includes(result.external_id)) {
        finalResult[result.external_id].push(result.tag_name);
    } else {
    alreadyPushedIds.push(result.external_id);
    Object.assign(finalResult, { [result.external_id]: [result.tag_name] });
    }
}
```

```js
results.reduce<{ [key: string]: string[] }>((
      acc: { [key: string]: string[] },
      val: { external_id: string; tag_name: string }
    ) => {
      if (!acc[val.external_id]) {
        acc[val.external_id] = [];
      }
      acc[val.external_id].push(val.tag_name);
      return acc;
    }, {})
```